# when I get excel data of binary format from using requests.get() method, how can i get to know the number of sheets in the data?

Tags: pandas, excel

I'm trying to crawl excel files and

I got a respond by using get() method.

`res = requests.get(url, headers={'user-agent':ua})`

```
print(type(res.content))
<class 'bytes'>
```

I already knew it had 6 sheets, so I could saved each sheet like

```
for i in range(5):
df_data = pd.read_excel(res.content, sheet_name=i)
df_data.to_excel(db+ f'{sheet}.xlsx')
```

However, What if I don't know the number of sheets of downloaded data?

How can I know the number of sheets??

Moreover, what if I don't even know the extension of binary data? how can I find the right extension of data to utilize?

Thanks in advance!!

I Do want to know the number of sheets